# Binding a List to a UserControl Property

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, user-controls, windows-8

I'm having a bit of trouble getting my User Control to bind to a List<>. It works great when I attempt to do something like:

```
public string Map
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(MapProperty); }
    set
    {
        SetValue(MapProperty, value);
    }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty MapProperty =
DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Map",
    typeof(string), 
    typeof(GamePane), 
    new PropertyMetadata(     
        "Unknown",            
        ChangeMap)
    );
```

However, if I attempt to use a Property that is anything more then a string, int or float etc I get "the member 'Property Name' is not recognized or is not accessible". Example:

```
public List<string> Players
{
    get { return (List<string>)GetValue(PlayersProperty); }
    set
    {
        SetValue(PlayersProperty, value);
    }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty PlayersProperty =
DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Players",   
    typeof(List<string>),
    typeof(GamePane),  
    new PropertyMetadata(     
        new List<string>(), 
        ChangePlayers)
    );
```

Besides the types the code is exactly the same.

I have seen that I might need to use a BindableList, however, this does not appear to exist for Windows 8 projects.

Can someone point me in the proper direction or show me an alternative approach.

Edit: By request, the XAML for my List View, which I attempt to bind the string list to:

```
<ListView x:Name="PlayerList" SelectionMode="None" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" ItemsSource="{Binding Players}"
                  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Margin="6,-1,0,0" IsHitTestVisible="False">
```

Then, in my main view, I draw my GridView, which create my Bindings and has the exception:

```
<GridView
    x:Name="currentGames"
    AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemsGridView"
    AutomationProperties.Name="Items"
    TabIndex="1"
    Padding="12,0,12,0"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource itemsViewSource}}"
    SelectionMode="None"
    IsSwipeEnabled="false" Grid.Row="1" Margin="48,-20,0,0" Height="210" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:GamePane Map="{Binding Map}" Time="{Binding TimeRemaining}" Players="{Binding Players}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

Interestingly, while this XAML breaks both Visual Studio's and Blend's designer, the code will execute. Albeit, my Players will not show up.

Comment: Can you post also the XAML where you try to bind to the property?

Comment: I've posted the XAML from both my MainPage and UserControl that handle the binding I am having trouble with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, it works.

Here's the XAML to bind to it:

```
<Grid Background="Black">
    <local:MyUserControl x:Name="MyControl" />
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyList, ElementName=MyControl}" />
</Grid>
```

And here's the user control code:

```
public sealed partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public MyUserControl()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string[] MyList
    {
        get { return new string[] { "One", "Two", "Three" }; }
    }
}
```